# Creating a .txt document with **kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

How do I get my `**kwargs` into my newly created .txt document?

```
def credentials_file(filename, **kwargs):
    open(filename, "w")
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        filename.write("{}: {}\n" .format(key, value))


credentials_file("credentials.txt", First_Name="John", 
Last_Name="Cleese")
```

Comment: `filename.write`?

Comment: I tried that in line 4. Or did I make a mistake I am unaware of right now?

Comment: @Pio Yes. Filename is a string. Nothing else. `filename.write` makes no sense.

Answer (score 6):

`open(filename, "w")` does **not** transforms `filename` from a string into a *file handler*, it opens the file (sometimes creating a file) and **returns** a handle.

So you should use:

```
def credentials_file(filename, **kwargs):
    handle = open(filename, "w")
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        handle.write("{}: {}\n" .format(key, value))
    handle.close()
```

It is however in case of a handle, better to use a `with` context:

```
def credentials_file(filename, **kwargs):
    with open(filename, "w") as handle:
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            handle.write("{}: {}\n" .format(key, value))
```

the context will automatically close the file when you jump out of the `with`.

Comment: Oh wow, now I get it. That makes much more sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: Very nice use of bold text to illustrate essential variables and methods in the code. +1

Comment: @PRMoureu: the highlighting is still active I think... I see the code in different colors. Usually `<!-- language-all: lang-python -->`, etc are useful if SO fails to detect the programming language.